# how to load a same funcion twice in javascript file

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am having init function and i want to load this init function again by calling the same method.
I just want to refresh once the same loaded page.

Example code is

```
Ext.onReady(Kbase.init, Kbase);
```

this will call

```
Kbase.init = function(){
    /* ... */
}
```

I just want to load this init function again in same js file.
Or else I just want to refresh once the same js page.

Answer (score 1):

Just try to call init function once more.

```
Ext.onRead(Kbase.init, Kbase);
/* ... */
$("button").click(function(){
    Kbase.init;
});
```

Or check if there is any "updated" function for that object.

Answer (score 1):

**Use Below Code**

```
var cnt=1;
var repeatFunction = setInterval(function(){
if(cnt<3){
    //callYourFunction();
    alert('function called :'+cnt);
    Kbase.init;        
}
else{
    repeatFunction =null;
}
    cnt=cnt+1;
},500);
```

Use `setInterval()` will meet your task.